# Is there a Python equivalent of range(n) for multidimensional ranges?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, range

On Python, range(3) will return [0,1,2]. Is there an equivalent for multidimensional ranges?

```
range((3,2)) # [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1)]
```

So, for example, looping though the tiles of a rectangular area on a tile-based game could be written as:

```
for x,y in range((3,2)):
```

Note I'm not asking for an implementation. I would like to know if this is a recognized pattern and if there is a built-in function on Python or it's standard/common libraries.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In numpy, it's [`numpy.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html).  Also have a look at [`numpy.ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html).

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
for x, y in np.ndindex((3,2)):
    print(x, y)
```

This yields:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
```

Comment: +1: The syntax for that is alarmingly similar to what the OP originally asked for. Well played!

Comment: As Li-aung pointed this is alarmingly similar to what I asked for, so it is, undoubtedly, the best answer to the topic.

Comment: Li-aung Yip answer is great, too, and has some learning on it as it shows the cartesian product can be used for the same purpose.

Comment: This makes loads of things with Numpy Arrays gigantically more generic, soo powerful.

Answer (score 40):

You could use `itertools.product()`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for (i,j,k) in itertools.product(xrange(3),xrange(3),xrange(3)):
...     print i,j,k
```

The multiple repeated `xrange()` statements could be expressed like so, if you want to scale this up to a ten-dimensional loop or something similarly ridiculous:

```
>>> for combination in itertools.product( xrange(3), repeat=10 ):
...     print combination
```

Which loops over ten variables, varying from `(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` to `(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)`.

---

In general `itertools` is an insanely awesome module. In the same way regexps are vastly more expressive than "plain" string methods, `itertools` is a very elegant way of expressing complex loops. [You owe it to yourself to read the `itertools` module documentation.](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) It will make your life more fun.

Comment: just a tiny improvement over your last answer:
`for c in product(*([xrange(5)]*3)): print c`: from (0,0,0) to (4,4,4)

Comment: It's actually better to use `itertools.tee()` if you want exact replicas - I believe the underlying implementation is more efficient due to caching.

Comment: @agf: good catch - evidently time for me to sleep. Edited to that effect.

Answer (score 29):

There actually is a simple syntax for this.  You just need to have two `for`s:

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(2)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: This is good, but I would like to point that it can get a little verbose:
for (x,y) in [(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(2)]:

Answer (score 8):

That is the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Basic_properties) of two lists therefore:

```
import itertools
for element in itertools.product(range(3),range(2)):
    print element
```

gives this output:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `product` from `itertools` module.

```
itertools.product(range(3), range(2))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at `numpy.meshgrid`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

which will give you the X and Y grid values at each position in a mesh/grid. Then you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xrange(3),xrange(2))
zip(X.ravel(),Y.ravel()) 
#[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
```

or

```
zip(X.ravel(order='F'),Y.ravel(order='F')) 
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: it would be good to also mention `numpy.mgrid` and `numpy.ogrid` here.

Answer (score 3):

## `ndindex()` is NOT the ND equivalent of `range()`

(despite some of the other answers here).

It works for your simple example, but it doesn't permit arbitrary `start`, `stop`, and `step` arguments.  It only accepts `stop`, and it hard-codes `start` to `(0,0,...)` and hard-codes `step` to `(1,1,...)`.

Here's an implementation that acts more like the built-in `range()` function.  That is, it permits arbitrary `start`/`stop`/`step` arguments, yet it works on *tuples* instead of mere integers.  Like built-in `range()`, it returns an iterable.

```python
from itertools import product

def ndrange(start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
        start = (0,) * len(stop)
    if step is None:
        step = (1,) * len(start)

    assert len(start) == len(stop) == len(step)    
    for index in product(*map(range, start, stop, step)):
        yield index
```

Example:

```
In [7]: for index in ndrange((1,2,3), (10,20,30), step=(5,10,15)):
   ...:     print(index)
   ...:
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 18)
(1, 12, 3)
(1, 12, 18)
(6, 2, 3)
(6, 2, 18)
(6, 12, 3)
(6, 12, 18)
```

## For numpy users

If your code is numpy-based, then it's probably more convenient to work directly with `ndarray` objects, rather than an iterable of tuples.  It might also be faster. The following implementation is faster than using the above *if you planned to convert the result to ndarray*.

```
def ndrange_array(start, stop=None, step=1):
    """
    Like np.ndindex, but accepts start/stop/step instead of
    assuming that start is always (0,0,0) and step is (1,1,1),
    and returns an array instead of an iterator.
    """
    start = np.asarray(start)
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
        start = (0,) * len(stop)

    def ndindex(shape):
        """Like np.ndindex, but returns ndarray"""
        return np.indices(shape).reshape(len(shape), -1).transpose()

    shape = (stop - start + step - 1) // step
    return start + step * ndindex(shape)
```

Comment: Just in time for the sprint!

Comment: good job for providing a full answer. when most of the answers are focusing only on the single use case that OP mentioned, you actually provided an answer for the question of equivalent range function for multidimensional case, which covers all the use cases