# best way to create numpy array from FOR loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there a better way to create a multidimensional array in numpy using a FOR loop, rather than creating a list?  This is the only method I could come up with:

```
import numpy as np

a = []
for x in range(1,6):
    for y in range(1,6):
        a.append([x,y])
a = np.array(a)
print(f'Type(a) = {type(a)}.  a = {a}')
```

EDIT: I tried doing something like this:

```
a = np.array([range(1,6),range(1,6)])
a.shape = (5,2)
print(f'Type(a) = {type(a)}.  a = {a}')
```

however, the output is not the same. I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you understand what that 2nd try did?  Even it didn't produce what you want, it's important to understand that expression.

Answer (score 3):

You could [preallocate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) the array before assigning the respective values:

```
a = np.empty(shape=(25, 2), dtype=int)
for x in range(1, 6):
    for y in range(1, 6):
        index = (x-1)*5+(y-1)
        a[index] = x, y
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you had a look at [numpy.ndindex](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html)? This could do the trick:

```
a = np.ndindex(6,6)
```

You could have some more information on [Is there a Python equivalent of range(n) for multidimensional ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093293/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-rangen-for-multidimensional-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace double for-loop with [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product 
import numpy as np

np.array(list(product(range(1,6), range(1,6))))
```

For me creating array from list looks natural here. Don't know how to skip them in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is difficult to predict the total element number and shape at stage of selecting array elements due to some `if` statement inside a loop.

In this case, put all selected elements in flat array:

```
a = np.empty((0), int)
for x in range(1,6):  # x-coordinate
    for y in range(1,6):  # y-coordinate
        if x!=y:  # `if` statement
            a = np.append(a, [x, y])
```

Then, given the lengths of one array dimension (in our case there are 2 coordinates) one can use `-1` for the unknown dimension:

```
a.shape = (-1, 2)
a
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [5, 3],
       [5, 4]])
```